# 3ds Max Rendering

Tags: rendering, 3d-modeling, 3ds-max, modeling

Hey I render 36 frames from different angles to PNG files on 3Ds Max 2013 but now I want to hide a model and make it so all the parts its blocking to also become transparent.

If you don't understand what I mean I don't want to simply "hide" the instance because then all the parts in the back that otherwise would be invisible would become visible, I just want those parts to become transparent as if I "subtract" the image of the hidden instance out of the final render image.

EDIT: ANYONE??

Answer (score 0):

Frame set A:  Render the frames with only the (object to be subtracted) present.

Take the alpha channel of frame set A and use it to subtract (object to be subtracted) from the original set of frames.